# How to Join images of different size - adding Footer Image to all images (BULK)

Tags: image, join, image-editing

I have more than 8000 images of different dimensions.

I want my footer image to adjust its width according to each image size and join the image at the bottom.

I am a basic person and will not be able to program it myself.

Is there any software that will help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ImageMagick, which is installed on most Linux distros and available for OS X, all good OSes and Windows from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

So, if you have an image like this:

[image]

the code to add a label would be pretty easy like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity center -background lime -fill yellow -stroke black -pointsize 36 label:"My Photo" -append result.jpg
```

[image]

I am not suggesting that is a good colour scheme, I am just showing you how/where to set the colours, and you can change them as you wish. If you now run the same code on a different size image like this:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

There are countless examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/).

Please copy some of your images to a test folder and practice with the code below in there so you don't mess up your original photos. As I said, I don't really "do" Windows, but the code will look like this to do all the `PNG` and `JPG` files in a directory:

```
for %a in (*.PNG *.JPG) do convert "%a" -gravity center -background lime -fill yellow -stroke black -pointsize 36 label:"My Photo" -append "%a"
```

There are some good examples of using `FOR` loops [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) it has the paste special option that will resize and paste your footer image below the original one in one shot. But unfortunately it can't do it for you for the 8000 images.

To resize + merge a footer: Open your footer image, copy it (ctrl+c)

Now open your original image in IrfanView, go to Edit -> Paste Special -> to Bottom, it will resize & merge your footer under the original image.

IrfanView has also a batch conversion option to resize images in bulk but it can't join your images automatically. So it will help you with the resizing if needed.

To open the batch conversion in IrfanView, go to File -> Batch conversion/rename -> Advanced
From here you have tons of stuff to do among which the batch resize